# add empty line between group of items in string

Tags: android, string, vcf-vcard

I know this is probably one of dumbest questions ever but my brain seems off.
I have this method which makes a string out of vCard:

```
public static String process(String vCard) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> vCardData = parseData(vCard);
        if (vCardData != null) {
            StringBuilder readableVCard = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_COUNT; i++) {
                ArrayList<String> vCardDataField = vCardData.get(i);

                if (vCardDataField.size() > 0) {
                    String field = null;

                    if (i == FORMATTED_NAME) {
                        field = "Name: ";
                    } else if (i == PHONE_MOBILE) {
                        field = "Phone (mobile): ";
                    } else if (i == PHONE_HOME) {
                        field = "Phone (home): ";
                    } else if (i == PHONE_WORK) {
                        field = "Phone (work): ";
                    } else if (i == PHONE) {
                        field = "Phone: ";
                    } else if (i == FAX_HOME) {
                        field = "Fax (home): ";
                    } else if (i == FAX_WORK) {
                        field = "Fax (work): ";
                    } else if (i == PAGER) {
                        field = "Pager: ";
                    } else if (i == EMAIL_HOME) {
                        field = "Email (home): ";
                    } else if (i == EMAIL_WORK) {
                        field = "Email (work): ";
                    } else if (i == EMAIL) {
                        field = "Email: ";
                    } else if (i == ORGANISATION) {
                        field = "Company: ";
                    } else if (i == JOB_TITLE) {
                        field = "Job title: ";
                    } else if (i == ADDRESS_HOME) {
                        field = "Address (home): ";
                    } else if (i == ADDRESS_WORK) {
                        field = "Address (work): ";
                    } else if (i == ADDRESS) {
                        field = "Address: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_SKYPE) {
                        field = "Skype: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_GOOGLE) {
                        field = "Google Talk: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_JABBER) {
                        field = "Jabber: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_YAHOO) {
                        field = "Yahoo: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_MSN) {
                        field = "MSN: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_ICQ) {
                        field = "ICQ: ";
                    } else if (i == IM_AIM) {
                        field = "AIM: ";
                    } else if (i == TWITTER) {
                        field = "Twitter: ";
                    } else if (i == BIRTHDAY) {
                        field = "Birthday: ";
                    } else if (i == ANNIVERSARY) {
                        field = "Anniversary: ";
                    } else if (i == NOTES) {
                        field = "Notes: ";
                    } else if (i == WEBSITE) {
                        field = "Website: ";
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (readableVCard.length() != 0) {
                        readableVCard.append("\n");
                    }
                    readableVCard.append(field);

                    for (int j = 0; j < vCardDataField.size(); j++) {
                        if (j != 0) {
                            readableVCard.append("; ");
                        }
                        readableVCard.append(vCardDataField.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }

            if (readableVCard.length() != 0) {
                String textVCard = readableVCard.toString();
                try {
                    textVCard = qpDecoder.decode(readableVCard.toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.e("VCard to UTF-8", e.getMessage());
                }

                return (textVCard);
            }
        }

        return (null);
    }
```

So my current output is like this:

```
Name: Marko
Phone(mobile):1312
Phone(fax):441231
Phone(home):543534
Email(home):dddd
Email(work):eeee
Email(other):aaaa
```

What I want is to add a line break between groups (name/phone/email) so I get something like this:

```
Name: Marko

Phone(mobile):1312
Phone(fax):441231
Phone(home):543534

Email(home):dddd
Email(work):eeee
Email(other):aaaa

Addressblablabla
.
.
.

IMsblablabla
.
.
.
```

Can someone help please? 
Thanks.

Comment: Create a resource like so (or put it in the code `&lt;br /&gt;`) like so: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="new_line">&lt;br /&gt;</string>
</resources>` and use it like you want. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: guys I know how to add an empty line, I actually need help how to place it between groups of item (between last phone and first email)

Comment: Then add the new line after `field = "Name: ";` for example, after that for each group like the `FAX` group, use a common `if` statement like that: `else if (i == FAX_HOME || i == FAX_WORK){
  if (i == FAX_HOME) {
      field = "Fax (home): ";
  }
  else if (i == FAX_WORK) {
    field = "Fax (work): ";
  }
  field = field.concat("Your new_line character");
}` - you'll get the idea. That is of course of only one FAX number is entered, do you know the order in the vcard or how many informations are there?

Comment: there is never same order or number of informations, thats the point :)

Comment: hehe ok, then you should put all the constants like `FORMATTED_NAME`, `PHONE_MOBILE` etc. in an `int array[15][2]` (example values). Before determining if the field equals to, for example `PHONE_MOBILE`. Then, in the same array, put a count. After that, inthe section that you're `readableVCard.append("\n");`, check if the count equals zero for example, if it does, append the new line one more time, if not, decrease the count. It's very simple, you can even write it yourself and accept the answer :)

Comment: ah my brain got back to work and I did it other way but thanks for help anyway. :)

Comment: You can paste the answer and accept it by yourself. It will even give you a badge I think, but the most important thing is to help someone with the current problem in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the string array, splitting by : and then checking if next item starts with current. If it does, then do nothing, if it doesn't you add the line break to current item and replace it in the array.

Note: splitting with : also separates all phone (xxx) types. To avoid this, you can create enum type, map type to Phone if the string starts with "phone" and use that enum as current type while iterating through the array. If current type if different than next type you add line break.

Answer (score 0):

> You can append line separator via
>   System.getProperty("line.separator");

Comment: well i know that, but how do I add it between group of items? How can I track which was last group of item ( phone, email, address etc) so I know to put /n there?